# nginx proxypath https redirect fails without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I'm trying to setup Nginx to forward requests to several backend services using proxy_pass.

The links on the pages that lack trailing slashes do have `https://` in front, but get redirected to a http request with a trailing slash - which ends in connection refused - I only want these services to be available through https.

So if a link is too `https://example.com/internal/errorlogs`

in a browser when loaded `https://example.com/internal/errorlogs` gives `Error Code 10061: Connection refused` (it redirects to `http://example.com/internal/errorlogs/`)

If I manually append the trialing slash `https://example.com/internal/errorlogs/` it loads

I've tried with varied trailing forward slashes appended to the proxypath and location in proxy.conf to no effect, have also added `server_name_in_redirect off;`

This happens on more than one app under nginx, and works in apache reverse proxy

Config files;

proxy.conf

```
location /internal {
    proxy_pass        http://localhost:8081/internal;
    include proxy.inc;
}
.... more entries ....
```

sites-enabled/main

```
server {
    listen 443;

    server_name example.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    include proxy.conf;

    ssl on;
}
```

proxy.inc

```
proxy_connect_timeout   59s;
proxy_send_timeout      600;
proxy_read_timeout      600;
proxy_buffer_size       64k;
proxy_buffers           16 32k;
proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_hide_header       Vary;

proxy_busy_buffers_size         64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size      64k;

proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding         '';
proxy_ignore_headers    Cache-Control           Expires;
proxy_set_header        Referer                 $http_referer;
proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
proxy_set_header        Cookie                  $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server      $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Ssl         on;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       https;
```

curl output

```
-$ curl -I -k https://example.com/internal/errorlogs/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.5
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 23:32:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 14327

-$ curl -I -k https://example.com/internal/errorlogs
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.0.5
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 23:32:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 127
Location: http://example.com/internal/errorlogs/
```

Comment: Can you check if this redirect from https to http is result from a 3XX response?

Comment: Please, add the result for `curl -I https://example.com/internal/errorlogs`

Comment: yep, you're right!, do you think I should try add a scheme rewrite rule to proxy.inc?

Comment: See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/812461/162443).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw you added the `server_name_in_redirect` directive, but you need `proxy_redirect` directive on the location session

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect

You will add something like that

```
proxy_redirect http://example.com/ /;
```

Comment: `proxy_redirect http://example.com/ /; #Works `   
`proxy_redirect http://$host/ /; #Fails`

Comment: also, works regardless of `server_name_in_redirect`

Comment: I know, they are similar, but the `server_name_in_redirect` acts on redirects inside nginx, and `proxy_redirect` acts in redirect responses from upstream proxies.

Comment: RE: Voting, what I can tell you is that no one person has voted, in any way, more than 4 times on your posts. Beyond that, I can't tell.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 it disappeared a few minutes after I sent that message, I thought that was strange because all had the same time, thanks anyway.

Comment: That's because our system *does* detect such events and undoes them in time. I once had someone upvote me 15 times, and it got rolled back.