# Stop nginx from appending backslash and redirecting when a dir is present with same name

Tags: nginx

I have a particular server setup where `blog.html` is next to a `blog/` dir.

[image]

The problem is that when a URL is directed to blog.html, e.g., `https://website.com/blog`, a backslash is automatically appended (presumably because it sees that a dir is present) which then results in a forbidden error.

[image]

`blog.html` serves as an index, and `blog/` contains sub pages:

`https://website.com/blog` should be valid and show all articles 
`https://website.com/blog/` should result in a redirect to `https://website.com/blog`
`https://website.com/blog/article-1` should resolve to the corresponding subpage.

I've tried to redirect if there's a trailing backslash, e.g.,: `rewrite ^/(.+)/$ $1 permanent;` but none of the variations I've tried have helped.

Posts I've attempted to implement to no avail:

[How to stop nginx 301 auto redirect when trailing slash is not in URI?](https://serverfault.com/questions/759762/how-to-stop-nginx-301-auto-redirect-when-trailing-slash-is-not-in-uri/812461#812461)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973947/how-to-redirect-no-www-to-www-under-jwilder-nginx-proxy
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129752/rewrite-url-in-jwilder-nginx-proxy-docker-container

How can I configure nginx to not auto resolve to the directory and accept the non-backslash URL without issue?

Comment: `/blog` URI refers to the file `blog` in default nginx configuration. Please add the output of `nginx -T` in your question so we can see the current configuration.